# Connection error after successfully executing remote actions

Tags: ansible

I wrote a simple script to delete users.

```
---
- name: play
  hosts: all 
  tasks:
  - name: delete users
    user:
      name: automation
      state: absent
      force: yes 
      remove: yes
```

It got an error:  `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "userdel: user automation is currently used by process 9781\nuserdel: Permission denied.\nuserdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n", "name": "automation", "rc": 1}`  Whoops, my ansible.cfg says to run as user automation by default.  I have to run as root to delete the user.  Add `become: yes` to the script.

Run it again, and then it says `FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Welcome to HAProxy server\nautomation@fresh1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)."}` !?  ssh is set up so user automation can ssh to root without passwords.  And you can see it DID successfully connect, as it got the "Welcome" MOTD.  And in fact it **DID** delete the users!  So after doing all that successfully, why did it give this fail-to-connect error ??

Then I removed the become: yes from the script and ran it again, so the script is back to the state it was before, but now the automation users are gone.  Now it says `UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Welcome to HAProxy server\nautomation@fresh1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}`.  I assume that error is because become=no, so by default it tried to connect as automation, BUT that user is deleted now.

So what's with the connection error in the second step, since it successfully connected and deleted the user??  I pored over the -vvv logs but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: how are you supplying root password when `become: yes` was used?

Comment: None needed.  I have a NOPASSWD: entry in sudoers.

Comment: Wait, no.  I have ssh set up to allow that user to log into root w/o password.

Comment: see this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/become/sudo.html#parameter-become_flags

Comment: it says default is `"-H -S -n"` ,  , and  `-S, --stdin                 read password from standard input. You need to change the `ansible_sudo_flags` to not to use `-S`

Comment: But it's NOT reading the password from stdin.  It's logging in just fine without any interaction.  But just to be sure I put the ansible_sudo_flag setting in ansible.cfg -- no change.

Comment: I think ansible is connecting as user automation and then becoming (sudo-ing) to root to do its job.  And its job is deleting the automation user that's "under" the root login.  So once it's finished deleting automation, the root shell exits, and finds itself in user automation.  Which probably tries to access something in its home directory, which is gone now.  That would also explain the "No such file or directory: '/home/automation'" error at the end of the long error message.

Comment: Aha!  Yes that's it.  If I specify "-u root" so it CONNECTS as root, instead of using "become" (log in as automation and then su to root), then there is no error.

Thanks for letting me bounce ideas off you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comment above, the problem was that I was using "become."  Which causes ansible to login as my default user "automation," and then su to root.  So root deleted the user -- which was the user "automation" -- and exited back to the automation login shell.  But at that point the /home/automation dir was gone, and it got an error.

Using `-u root` (to log in as root, not as automation) instead of "become" got rid of the error.